# which HTML helper bypasses all templates and renders a simple string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

this question I got from some tests:

> Which of the following templated HTML helpers of MVC bypasses all
>   templates and renders a simple string representation of the specified
>   model property?

and options:

1. Display
2. Label
3. DisplayText
4. Editor

as I understand, it means, that which helper displays property as string? The correct answer is Label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct answer is `DisplayText` and don't get confused with `DisplayTextFor` which is a strongly typed version of `DisplayText` and returns the annotation value of your model attribute (if predefined) or `null` otherwise